# How do I default the Date-picker in MS Access to the 0hrs 0min 0sec of the day?

Tags: ms-access, datepicker, vba

I am able to change the date using the date-picker however, the hrs:minutes:seconds from the previous selection follows as well making the day not start at the 0hs:0min:0sec.
let me explain:

I am using a frontend/backend Access/server tables and in Access Front end I have 
two date-pickers (txtFrom and txtTo) and 
one cmb box as period picker (cmbPeriod = Today, this week, this month, etc)

The dates on the date-pickers change in three ways and i am having issues with one of them.
   If you leave the cmbPeriod, txtFrom and txtTo blank the txtFrom and txtTo populate with the first and last date of all reports as follows:

```
If Me.cmbPeriod & "" = "" Then
        If Me.txtFrom & "" = "" Then Me.txtFrom = DMin("[Date]", "qryUnapprovedreports")
        If Me.txtTo & "" = "" Then Me.txtTo = DMax("[Date]", "qryUnapprovedReports")
    End If
```

When I use this method the following is an example:

```
txtFrom = 06/29/18 1:56:25 PM
txtTo   = 07/20/18 3:50:39 PM
```

Note: To operators time is irrelevant so i ask them to select only date.

When i change the date on the date-picker the hrs:min:sec follow me to the new date selected rather then the start of day: another example:

```
txtFrom Date-Picker = 07/13/2018. gives
txtFrom = 07/13/2018 1:56:25 PM and I need it as 
txtFrom = 07/13/2018 0:00:00 AM
```

This is Shortening my day and not including reports that are submitted before the time of 1:56 which is wrong.

How can i force Access date to pick the start of day and ignore or reset the time.

Answer (score 1):

**To remove the time from a date, you simply remove everything after the decimal point.**

There are several ways to do this, including [rounding](http://www.mathwords.com/r/rounding_a_number.htm) or [truncating](http://www.mathwords.com/t/truncating_a_number.htm).

With your example of:

```
DMax("[Date]", "qryUnapprovedReports")
```

...which is returning a DateTime, you can round it to midnight with:

```
ROUND(DMax("[Date]", "qryUnapprovedReports"),0)
```

...will round to the closest whole day (so `2001-01-01 4:20pm` becomes `2001-01-02 12:00am`), or,

```
INT(DMax("[Date]", "qryUnapprovedReports"))
```

..will truncate the date, so it cuts off the time (so `2001-01-01 4:20pm` becomes `2001-01-01 12:00am`)

---

Dates are stored in MS Office as numbers.

```
1 = 1 day

Therefore:
    0.5 = half a day (or "12:00 noon")
    0.25 = quarter day (or "6:00am")
    1 hour = 1/24th of a day = approx 0.041667
    1 second = approx 0.0000115740740740741
```

See this for more info:

- [**How to use dates and times in Excel**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel)

The same information applies to all MS Office applications. There are plenty more tutorials and code samples available online to help you work with dates and times in Access (or Excel).

Comment: Good on you for explaining the numeric basis of Date/Time values.  However my first impulse to extract "just the date" from a Date/Time value is this: `DateValue(DMax("[Date]", "qryUnapprovedReports"))`